# Logging in main process when using concurrent futures ProcessPoolExecutor

Tags: python, python-3.x, logging, multiprocessing, concurrent.futures

Any ideas on how can I get forked processes to log to main process ?

My setup is like this:

---

```
from itertools import repeat
from concurrent.futures import ProcessPoolExecutor

logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)

def worker_process(i, logger):
    logger.info(f"{i}")

with ProcessPoolExecutor(max_workers=4) as executor:
    logger.info("Starting")
    executor.map(worker_process, range(5), repeat(logger))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your worker processes do log to the main thread.
You're not seeing any log output because the default log level for your `logger` is higher than `INFO`.

Set the logging to `INFO` and you'll see output:

```py
from itertools import repeat
from concurrent.futures import ProcessPoolExecutor
import logging

logging.basicConfig(level=logging.INFO)
logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)


def worker_process(i, logger):
    logger.info(f"{i}")


with ProcessPoolExecutor(max_workers=4) as executor:
    executor.map(worker_process, range(5), repeat(logger))
```

Result:

```
INFO:__main__:0
INFO:__main__:4
INFO:__main__:3
INFO:__main__:1
INFO:__main__:2
```